# Index, Match, Maxifs giving me the wrong result (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, google-sheets-formula

I use this formula in other sheets to get the latest value found, meeting a criteria set in another column. This time, it's repeating the value for the first match, although I got the criteria changing for each row.

Inventory Table

|Number | Date  | Name | Code | Item | Unit | Qty | Type |

```
=arrayformula(IFERROR((INDEX('Inventory'!$A$7:$H;MATCH(maxifs('Inventory'!$B$7:$B;'Inventory'!$D$7:$D;$C7);'Inventory'!$B$7:$B;0);8));""))
```

I've tried all kinds of tweaks, but even so...

Thank you!

Antonio

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T5FL9Gt6a6-g4NE-YjkgdYo2yzKHdVQluuQ_1nOZoLY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C7:C; 
 SORT({'Contagem - Estoque'!D7:D\
       'Contagem - Estoque'!H7:H\
       'Contagem - Estoque'!B7:B}; 3; 0); 2; 0)))
```

[image]